# How to add fulltext search to llamaindex

Tags: chatbot, langchain, large-language-model, llama-index

I am making chatbot that is capable of discussing movies with langchain and llamaindex. I am following this [guide](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/stable/end_to_end_tutorials/chatbots/building_a_chatbot.html#how-to-build-a-chatbot). I wish llamaindex performs not only search with vector knn, but also adds some results based on direct keyword hits. Is there a way to add this type of search?

Comment: you can add database support like milvus  for storing vector indexes and then you can leverage the functionality of full text search.

Comment: Could you please specify the full text search requirements. because there are a lot of searches (Relevance, Similarity) aspects & databases are available on the internet. So,  specify the details for you question

Answer (score 1):

If you want both keyword and vector search, then you can create a [Fusion Retriever](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/retrievers/reciprocal_rerank_fusion.html) which is a combination of BM25+Vector search. The reranking part is specified by: `mode="reciprocal_rerank"` in the docs; which is optional. The keyword search can also done by [BM25 Retriever](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/retrievers/bm25_retriever.html) alone.